# vee-validate's useFieldArray only works with deconstruct

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

Good day to all,

can someone explain me why vee-validates `useFieldArray` only works correctly when I deconstruct it?

Template:

```
        // For the working example I use "fields" instead of fieldArray.fields.
        // Nothing more, nothing less
        <div v-for="(field, idx) in fieldArray.fields" 
             class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div>
                <FormControl :id="`${props.type}[${idx}].name`"></FormControl>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Checkbox :id="`${props.type}[${idx}].value`"></Checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Working:

```
const form = useForm({initialValues: {[props.type]: getInitialFormValues()}});
const {fields, push} = useFieldArray(props.type)
```

Not working:

```
const form = useForm({initialValues: {[props.type]: getInitialFormValues()}});
const fieldArray = useFieldArray(props.type)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you need wrap values to ref(), if you do not deconstruct object.

Try this

```
const form = useForm({initialValues: {[props.type]: getInitialFormValues()}});
```

change to

```
import { ref } from 'vue';

const form = ref(useForm({initialValues: {[props.type]: getInitialFormValues()}}));
```

(for vue >= 3)